# How to boot 32-bit Linux kernel with 64-bit EFI Grub?

Tags: grub2, grub, bios, uefi

I have an ASUS ME176CX tablet, which only has 64-bit EFI booting support. No legacy option. But there are device drivers for 32-bit only Linux. How do I boot a 32-bit Linux OS through 64-bit Grub in EFI mode?